# Вывод с двух коллекций одновременно

Tags: c#, list

У меня есть две коллекции, которые нужно вывести в одном цикле.
Как мне лучше всего это реализовать? Можно ли использовать `foreach` или нет?

Comment: Вывести две коллекции в одном цикле можно в очень ограниченном числе случаев. Удручает качество задаваемых вопросов и полное отсутствие желания использовать собственные мозги. foreach в общем случае использует итератор привязанный к конкретной  коллекции - дальше попробуйте додумать сами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach (var item in list1.Union(list2))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

foreach (var tuple in list1.Zip(list2, Tuple.Create)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1 + tuple.Item2);
}

foreach (var item in list1.Concat(list2))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: Ну справедливости ради во всех случаях, Вами представленных, Вы работаете с новой и единственной коллекцией :). Ну а что касается исходного вопроса, то по моему это на уровне младшей группы детсада, типа - а можно ли спастись от дождя, нырнув с головой в пруд.

Comment: не могли бы пояснить, что это и как?

Comment: @VladislavsGeidans вся суть заключается в  том чтоб из двух коллекции сделать одну и пройтись по ней foreach. Например можно еще и list1.AddRang(list2) использовать.

Answer (score 5):

Если это какое то заумное задание для школьников где необходимо проявить смекалку то я могу предложить следующий вариант как костыль года :

```
        List<int> list1 = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { -1, -2, -3,-4,-5 };

        int maxSize = list1.Count;

        if (maxSize < list2.Count)
            maxSize = list2.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; ++i)
        {
            if (i < list1.Count)
                Console.WriteLine("list1 [" + i + "]:" + list1[i]);
            if (i < list2.Count)
                Console.WriteLine("list2 [" + i + "]:" + list2[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Действительно костыль =)

Comment: Надо еще сделать 
`List<int> list3 = new List<int>{0,1,2,3,4};
foreach (int index in list3)
{/*your code*/}`. Просили же foreach! )